# UFT script pause when closing Remote Desktop

Tags: hp-uft, rdp

Im launching an UFT script in a Remote machine. The access to that Remote machine es from my Local machine (the script is launched in the Remote, not from local).

The problem is that if I close the Remote Desktop, the script pauses until I start another time the machine.

How can the script continue with the Remote Desktop closed? I tried going in UFT to Tools -> Options -> Run session -> allow scripting when RDP is closed and entering user and pass with a verified conection, but does not work.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

More of a workaround. Have not seen this flag working for some time, but that could just be inexperience.

Alternatives are:

1. Configure a service account that logs in and starts UFT Run time as soon as the server is started.
2. Stay logged into the remote session and disable auto screen lock.
3. Use mouse move tools like MouseJiggle to stop the screen locking

UFT documentation give several places where settings must be configured. (during installation, post installation)